# LWP::Curl Debian Wheezy

Tags: perl, curl, debian

I'm trying to install the LWP::Curl module for a project.

So I first installed it via CPAN:

```
cpan install LWP::Curl
```

but when I try to execute my code, I'm facing this error:

```
Can't locate LWP/Curl.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/franck/perl5/lib/perl5/5.14.2/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/franck/perl5/lib/perl5/5.14.2 /home/franck/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi /home/franck/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./test.pl line 4.BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 4.
```

So, I tried to install LWP::UserAgent::Cached too but nothing happens, I'm always stuck with this error.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping.

My code is only including the libs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Curl;
```

Here is the content of /home/franck/perl:

```
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 franck franck 4096 mars   3 13:43 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 franck franck 4096 mars   3 13:43 lib
drwxr-xr-x 3 franck franck 4096 mars   3 13:43 man
```

I checked the lib directory, only 5.14.2 is installed. I'm on a VM with a fresh Debian install so I don't think to have another perl version installed

And I tried to search the Cur.pm file:

```
root@vmtest:~$ find / -name "Curl.pm" -print
root@vmtest:~$
```

nothing returned.

And I already googled why the file is not present whereas I installed the module.

Sorry if I ask something kind of trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Finally \o/ after many many hours of scrolling over logs lines of CPAN I installed libcurl4-gnutls-dev and librtmp-dev packages and it solves my problem.

I don't understand why those are not a dependency of libcurl package on Debian. I tried on Arch Linux and it works at the first time.

Thank you again for your help and sorry for disturbing.